# Reading pixel Data in Fragment Shader

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am doing a photo Editing application in Metal iOS. I am having a texture of image. I want to have a tool when user taps the texture I want to make the tapped point(a square area around tapped point) I want to read that specific area and I want to read the color and I want to make it grayscale.

I know we can read the pixel data of texture in Kernel function. Is it possible to read the pixel data in Fragment Shader and do the above scenario.

Comment: On iOS, fragment shaders can receive the color from the color attachment as an input variable. Decorate the parameter (or field of a `[[stage_in]]` struct parameter) with the `[[color(m)]]` attribute. See the Programmable Blending section in the Metal Shading Language Specification, where conversion to grayscale is actually given as an example.

Comment: @KenThomases I will explain the problem. I have a texture 0f 2732*2048 in Size. . when user taps in (732.5,456.6). I need to make a square around a tapped point of size 3 pixels width and I want to read that pixel I want to append that pixel directly. In some scenarios I want to gray scale. Some Secenarios I want to use like eraser tool in Drawing Applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is the HelloCompute Metal example provided by Apple. Just download it and take a look at how a texture is rendered and how a shader can be used to convert color pixels to grayscale. The BasicTexturing example also shows how to do a plain texture render on its own.

Comment: I am drawing a RGB image in a Quad like Screen Size. In that texture i want to make like grayscale paint Brush. The places only where i touches needs to be turned to grayscale other places remains RGB.

Comment: Yes, well build it step by step. Get the basic render of RGB into a texture working in Metal first, then add on to that so that a second input texture (8 bit grayscale) is used to identify the pixel locations where the grayscale effect should be applied. Use 0 for no grayscale effect and 1 -> 255 for increasing amount of grayscale effect and then apply the effect on a pixel by pixel basis in the fragment shader. Your user level code will need to detect touches and render into the grayscale texture to identify where the touches are. You can render the touch input texture with CoreGraphics.